# which type of index is created internally when primary constraint is applied?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, constraints

I have read more about this and found similar question and Answers on Stackoverflow as well. But, I dint get the answer I want. I have read about indexes and constraints. The thing I didn't understand is, When I apply primary key constraint on a column, a clustered index is created internally and maintained.

In some other document they have said instead of clustered index Unique index is getting created. What I wanted to know from this is, which type of index is created internally when primary constraint is applied?

If, I create primary key constraint on the two columns. the unique or clustered index is getting created on those columns. How this primary key constraint work on those columns? because, if both columns are numeric and there is a chance of having same numeric values as well in the column. how come this situation get handled?

can anyone help me on this? thanks in advance.

Comment: [Create Primary Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I apply primary key constraint on a column, a clustered index is
>   created internally and maintained.
>
> In some other document they have said instead of clustered index
>   Unique index is getting created. What I wanted to know from this is,
>   which type of index is created internally when primary constraint is
>   applied?

In order to maintain `primary key` constraint, the `unique` index is created.

When you say "a **clustered** index is created internally and maintained", it is so just because you did not specify that you want it to be non-clustered, and by default if you don't specify this, primary key will be created as `clustered`.

Example:

```
alter table dbo.test
add constraint PK_test_VCode primary key nonclustered (VCode);
```

After executing this code you'll get `unique` `non-clustered` index `PK_test_VCode` that you can find under `Indexes` in `Object Explorer`.

> If, I create primary key constraint on the two columns. the **unique or
>   clustered** index is getting created on those columns.

Why did you put or between unique and clustered?

It can be both `clustered` and `unique`.

As I said above, `primary key` is always supported by `unique` index, that can be clustered or non-clustered, it's up to you to decide it.

> How this primary key constraint work on those columns? because, if
>   both columns are numeric and there is a chance of having same numeric
>   values as well in the column.

There is no such a chance because on every `insert`/`update` the uniqness is checked and if there is already a row with (n,m) in those columns any other row with (n,m) will be rejected by server.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome explanation. the reason I put or is, I'm not confirm that which one is getting created either unique or cluster. From your answer I come to know that Unique index is by default creating when primary key mentioned column. Since we haven't mentioned the type of cluster, cluster index will create by default. is that correct?

Comment: It's ALWAYS unique. And it can be clustered or non-clustered depending on your requirements